# Parsing a CSV into a custom HTML Format

Tags: javascript, python, csv

**Q:** I'm looking for some guidance regarding the best way to convert a .csv file into a list of divs in a specific format. Currently, I have parsed the data and created the format, however, I need some assistance with placing the data from .csv rows into the specified html areas in bold.

**E:** This is what the HTML format looks like and the CSV has about 325 rows of content as following - Page Links | Image Links | Title | Main Authors | Category | Year

```
<hr><div grid-row="" grid-pad="2" grid-gutter="4" grid-responsive=""><div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class="list-img"><a href="page-link" rel="history"><img style="width: 100%;" src="img-link" /></a></div><div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2"><div style="text-align: left;"><b>Title</b></div></div><div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2"><div style="text-align: left;">Authors</div></div><div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class=""><div style="text-align: left;">Category</div></div><div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class=""><div style="text-align: left;">Year</div></div></div>
```

**R:** So far I have been able to parse it into table view using CSV to HTML Table, however, I am having trouble formatting the export into the format above.

Any ideas or thoughts are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out!

I ended up converting the file to a .json and gave each row a unique id# or key value pair. After the file was in .json format and properly parsed, I then created a react application, copied over the html format that I listed above and used the map method.

For ever section that I wanted the unique data to be inserted I used the map method to insert the data by stating {item.name}, this allowed me to pull every element from the json file.

```js
import React from 'react'
import Data from './data.json'

export default function ListItem() {
  return (
    <div>
      { Data.map( item => {
        return(
          <div key={item.id}>
          <hr/>
            <div grid-row="" grid-pad="2" grid-gutter="4" grid-responsive="">
              <div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class="list-img">
                  <a href={item.pLinks} rel="history">
                      <img src={item.iLinks} />
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2">
                  <div class="list-spacing">
                      <b>{item.Title}</b>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2">
                  <div class="list-spacing">
                    {item.Author}
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class="">
                  <div class="list-spacing">
                    {item.Category}
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div grid-col="x8" grid-pad="2" class="">
                  <div class="list-spacing">
                    {item.Year}
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
      }) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Once I had the proper format and object.children in place I ran the react application and copied the entire html div.
I hope this helps anyone working with cargo or simple html website builders.